# Show option value in another div

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my database I have a table where I can add width, height and the matching price for this width x height.

Now I have the piece of code that shows the width x height in my dropdown menu on the site.
But the only thing I can't get to work that if I click on a width x height in my dropdown that the matching price of it shows somewhere else on my page.

```
<?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM shop_customoptions";
      $stmt = $conn->query( $query );

        $dropdown = "<select name='id' id='formaat_selecteren'>";
        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['prijs']}'>{$row['breedte']} x {$row['hoogte']}</option>";
         }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
        echo $dropdown;
    ?>
```

Can someone help me accomplish this?

I already found a solution with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $("#formaat_selecteren").change(function() {
          if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
          $(".price").html("&euro; " + $(this).val());
          } else {
          $(".price").empty();
          };
          });
        </script>
```

But it doesn't show the price with a , and I rather have a solution with PHP if there is one.

Comment: I would rather use `.on("change", function() {`. Make sure you have `$(document).ready(function() {` ... code here `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formaat_selecteren").change(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
    $(".price").html("&euro; " + String($(this).val()).replace('.',','));
    } else {
    $(".price").empty();
    };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still shows the price with a dot instead of a comma.

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want the dot preceding the cents 123.43 replaced with a comma? From 123.43 to 123,43?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. I want a price to show like this: € 70,60

Comment: No problem, to give a little explanation, we're taking the value of the element, turning it in to a string, and replacing the first period with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#formaat_selecteren").on("change", function() {
                if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
                    $(".price").html("$ " + String($(this).val()).replace('.',','));
                } else {
                    $(".price").empty();
                };
            });
        });
    </script>

    <span class="price"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still shows the price with a dot instead of a comma.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "But it doesn't show the price with a ,", I am guessing you mean the price is not formatted, eg "€2,000".  If that is true, you could try something like this.

PHP - add the formatted price as a data attribute.  This assumes you have your locale set in PHP, and you may wish a different format, see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

```
$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['prijs']}' data-price='" . money_format('%.2n', $row['prijs']) . "'>{$row['breedte']} x {$row['hoogte']}</option>";
```

Javascript - grab and use that data attribute:

```
$("#formaat_selecteren").change(function() {
    var formattedPrice = $(this).data('price');
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
        $(".price").html(formattedPrice);
    } else {
        $(".price").empty();
    };
});
```